# show that the sequence $x_n$ has the same sign

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

The number $x_n$ satisfy the recurrence relation 
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{[1+x_n+x_{n}^{2}]}{[2+x_n]}.
$$
If $x_1>-2$, show that $[x_n - x_{n+1}]$, $[x_{n}-1]$, $[x_{n+1}-1]$ all have the same sign when $n>1$.

If $x_1>-2$, show that $x_{n}$ tends to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

I understand that sequence has to be evaluated over the real field name but for this question, I am having difficulties recognizing what I am suppose to do. Anyone to guide me or provide ideas if not to solve the question. If I were required to test the convergence of such a sequence I think I could have tried but this sounds so abstract to me. Thank you in advance mathematicians.

Comment: Please, learn how to typesetmathematics with MathJax in this site: your post is very hard to understand.

Comment: Alright, I will next time, could be the device I am using which does support that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, look at the numerator.  See that

$$\require{cancel}x_n>-2\implies1+x_n+x_n^2\ge\frac34>0$$

Similarly, the same is true for the denominator.

$$2+x_n>0$$

Since both the numerator and denominator must be positive, $x_2$ must be positive and

$$x_2\ge\frac12$$

To show that $x_n-1$ has the same sign for $n>1$, consider $x_1<-1$ or $x_1>1$, $x_2>1$.  Thus, in those scenarios, we must show $x_n>1$.  For $-1<x_1<1$, we must show $x_n<1$.

If $x_n>1$, $x_{n+1}>1$, and similarly in the other way around for $x_n<1$.  You may prove by induction that for any $n>1$, $x_n$ will always have the same sign then.

By induction, this also proves $x_{n+1}-1$ will always have the same sign.

To show that $x_n-x_{n+1}$ will always have the same sign, use the recursive definition of $x_{n+1}$:

Assume it will always be positive:

$$\begin{align}
x_n & >x_{n+1} \\
x_n & >\frac{1+x_n+x_n^2}{2+x_n} \\
\cancel2x_n+\cancel{x_n^2} & > 1+\cancel{x_n}+\cancel{x_n^2} \\
x_n & > 1
\end{align}$$

So $x_n>x_{n+1}$ if $x_n>1$.  Similarly, one can show that $x_n<x_{n+1}$ if $x_n<1$ and $x_n=x_{n+1}$ if $x_n=1$.

For the sequence to converge, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L<\infty$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+x_n+x_n^2}{2+x_n}$$

$$L=\frac{1+L+L^2}{2+L}$$

$$\cancel2L+\cancel{L^2}=1+\cancel L+\cancel{L^2}$$

$$L=1$$

Thus, if the limit exists, it is equal to $1$.

To show it converges, see that it is bounded and that from the fact that $a_n-a_{n+1}$ will always have the same sign, we must have

$$1<\dots<a_4<a_3<a_2\\ \text{or} \\ a_2<a_3<a_4<\dots<1$$

or the trivial $a_n=1$.

Since the sequence cannot diverge, it must converge, and if it converges, it converges to $1$.